# Why is there a duplicate of a body when I i try moving vertices?

Tags: modeling

[image]I have an issue with model here, when i try moving edge, there seems to be a duplicate of the model in the background as seen in video. What might be the reason. I have used mirror modifier for the central loop.

https://youtu.be/vllgXg8xpvk

Comment: If you have the _Mirror_ modifier set to mirror the mesh on the X axis, everything that's on the positive X side will be replicated on the negative X **and vice versa**. So if you have one vertex on e.g. (1, 0, 0), it will be mirrored to (-1, 0, 0). If there already is a vertex in the original mesh it will not be replaced by the mirrored one but be mirrored itself to (1, 0, 0), which means you then have two duplicate vertices on (1, 0, 0) and two vertices on (-1, 0, 0).

Comment: And actually I don't understand what you mean by saying "I have used mirror modifier for the central loop." Usually the _Mirror_ modifier is used to mirror vertices that are **offset** from the origin center on the according axis.

Comment: .. and following up... a quick fix would be to check 'Bisect' on the relevant axis, possibly with 'Flip', to mirror the side you want.

Comment: Thanks all of you. Playing with bisect and flip worked.